# how to calculate zoom level in here android SDK

Tags: here-api

I have a request that want to know the zoom level that can just bring a position(GeoCoordinate) into current map view rect with a specific transform center.

Is there a method to calculate this zoom level in one time? but not use looply a small  zoom step to try setZoom and later check if this point is still in the view rect throgh ProjectToPixel function.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:
[Map#zoomTo(GeoBoundingBox, ViewRect, Animation, Orientation)](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-map.html#topic-apiref__zoomto-geoboundingbox-viewrect-map-animation-float)

It will directly move the map to a geoarea given a view rectangle. You can center the view rectangle at the transform center you wanted. The GeoBoundingBox is your current geo view port expanded to fit the position you want to fit in.

Comment: What coordinate system use this ViewRect object? And where its center?

Comment: ViewRect is just screen pixels